# Python 2D Autocorrelation fft - subtract mean or no?

Tags: python, image, fft, correlation, cross-correlation

I'm trying to compute the 2d auto and cross correlation of images using python (scipy.sig.fftconvolve). In terms of correlation one generally wants to subtract off the mean. However the equation for covariance says that

E[(X-E[X])(Y-E[Y])] == E[XY]-E[X]E[Y].

This means that I should theoretically be able to get the same results if I subtract the mean before doing the auto correlation or if I subtract the mean squared after the correlation. This is true for the case of the peak, or DC component, but not the rest of the image. And they look different, heres an example [autocorrelation with mean^2 subtracted off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUOMg.png)

[image]

and [autocorrelation with mean subtracted off image before doing correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46RXT.png)

[image]

So which way is the right way??

Comment: How are you dealing with the boundaries?  If you treat everything beyond the boundaries as zero, then if you don't subtract the mean, you'll get a big triangular overlay (or pyramidal in 2D) of the constant mean value disappearing into zero-land.

Comment: I was zero padding so yes I was seeing the pyramidal structure you mention. Is there a better way to handle the boundaries (if I don't want it to wrap on the actual image)?

Comment: Part 1: There are three approaches to boundaries, the first two you've already mentioned: 1) zero padding; 2) circular data; 3) correlate a small sample of the data to the full set and stay within the boundaries.  3 can work well if you're looking for a feature that's small relative to the size of the full data set.  Part 2: I think the uninteresting but often overwhelming pyramidal structure is a good enough reason to subtract the mean (ie, the math you showed isn't really considering this effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math you show doesn't consider the boundaries, but for real data one usually has to consider this issue.

First consider the case of constant data, and calculating the autocorrelation using zero-padding at the boundaries.  The result would be a triangle in 1D or a pyramid in 2D.  If you now super-impose a small ripple on this data, you'll still just see the triangle or pyramid.

But if you subtract the mean, the triangle/pyramid will go away, and you'll just be left with the autocorrelation of the ripple.  This is probably what you want.

Note the difference in scale of your colorbars for the two figures.  You're unlikely to see the underlying structure of the second figure within the first figure, where the pyramidal structure dominates.

So, in short, for zero-padded autocorrelations, you probably want to subtract the mean as a first step of the calculation.